# getting error on createObject

Tags: realm

i am getting

```
StartSensor Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void io.realm.ProxyState.setConstructionFinished()' on a null object reference
```

i try to create a new object with primarykey inside application class.
primarykeyFactory works it set the new key to "1" the database is empty at this moment.

```
public class SensorRecord extends MainApplication {
private final static String TAG = SensorRecord.class.getSimpleName();

private Realm mRealm;

public SensorRecord() {
    Realm.init(this);
    mRealm = getInstance(getRealmConfig());
}

public void StartSensor(long startTime) {
    long newprimekey = PrimaryKeyFactory.getInstance().nextKey(SensorData.class);
    try {
        mRealm.beginTransaction();
        SensorData mSensorData = mRealm.createObject(SensorData.class, newprimekey);
        mSensorData.setstarted_at(startTime);
        mRealm.commitTransaction();
        mRealm.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "StartSensor " + e.getMessage());
    }
}}
```

my main application class which init the realm config

```
public class MainApplication extends RealmBaseApplication {
private final static String TAG = MainApplication.class.getSimpleName();

Realm mRealm;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Realm.init(this);
    mRealm = getInstance(getRealmConfig());
    initializePrimaryKeyFactory();
}

public void initializePrimaryKeyFactory() {
    try {
        Log.v(TAG, "Start PrimaryKeyFactory ");
        PrimaryKeyFactory.getInstance().initialize(mRealm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "initializePrimaryKeyFactory " + e.getMessage());
    }
}}
```

and my realm config class

```
public abstract class RealmBaseApplication extends Application {
private RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration;

protected RealmConfiguration getRealmConfig() {
    if (realmConfiguration == null) {
        realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration
                .Builder()
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();
    }
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
    return realmConfiguration;
}

protected void resetRealm() {
    Realm.deleteRealm(getRealmConfig());
}}
```

kind regards
viktoria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok fixed by myself. had add butterknife tonight. and with that i add apt to my build.gradle... i removed

```
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8' 
        apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

and replaced

```
 apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```

with

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```